# Horizontal scrolling buttons for categories

Tags: flutter

I'd like to implement a horizontal scrolling buttons that will change the screen (page) like in the youtube app (shown below inside the red circle).

The tab bar doesn't have this functionality, it doesn't scroll.

How can I achieve this?

Any help or ideas are welcome.. thanks..

[image]

Comment: Refer ChoiceChips

Comment: @Prashant thanks for your comment. That's for the UI part, what about the actual changing of the screen?

Comment: use FilterChip inside ListView.Builder().
FilterChip is a widget from material.dart - https://imgur.com/a/ViD5hPu

Comment: You can use TabBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TabBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) widget, and set [`isScrollable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/isScrollable.html) to `true`:

```
TabBar(
    isScrollable: true, // <-- Set this
    tabs: <Widget>[ 
    Tab(
```

Note: The tab's length needs to be long enough for it to scroll, meaning, if it's some tabs aren't in the viewport, you can then scroll to view them.